# MongoDB query that gets all unique users

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm currently working with a MongoDB database. My problem is that I have many people with the same name, but they're different people and have different ages, birthplace, etc.

An example of the documents are:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6072fee3145c156c123ce3"),
        "Users" : [
                {
                        "name" : "John Davies",
                        "age" : NumberLong(35),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Edward Jones",
                        "age" : "blank",
                        "place_of_birth" : "Liverpool"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Daniel Rhys",
                        "age" : NumberLong(63),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                },
                {
                        "name" : " Evan Williams",
                        "age" : NumberLong(61),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "John Davies ",
                        "age" : NumberLong(21),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6072fee3145c156c321ef6"),
        " Users " : [
                {
                        "name" : "John Davies",
                        "age" : NumberLong(35),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Swansea"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Edward Jones",
                        "age" : "blank",
                        "place_of_birth" : "Liverpool"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Daniel Rhys ",
                        "age" : NumberLong(63),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Barry"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Evan Williams",
                        "age" : NumberLong(61),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "John Davies",
                        "age" : NumberLong(21),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                }
        ]
}
```

So my goal is to query this data in order to get all the names accompanied with the age and birthplace of each unique person once.

So the output should contain (I'm only putting in a table to show more clearly what the query results should be):

| Name | Age | Birth place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Davies | 35 | Cardigan |
| Edward Jones | Blank | Liverpool |
| Daniel Rhys | 63 | Cardigan |
| Evan Williams | 61 | Cardigan |
| John Davies | 21 | Cardigan |
| Daniel Rhys | 63 | Barry |
| John Davies | 35 | Swansea |

Any advice or guidance on the best approach would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `Users` array
- `$group` by `Users` object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `Users` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$Users" },
  { $group: { _id: "$Users" } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$_id" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rJ7fFfxXCSl)

---

Second option: Alternate of `$replaceRoot`,

- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$Users" },
  { $group: { _id: "$Users" } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id.name",
      age: "$_id.age",
      place_of_birth: "$_id.place_of_birth"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LkY6WX2omrX)

Comment: When applying this query I get the error "unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$replaceRoot' @turivishal

Comment: what is the version of your mongodb? it should be greater than 3.4

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.2.13

Comment: mongodb and mongodb shell version both are different, can you check mongodb server version, and where you executing this query?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the server version is MongoDB server version: 3.2.11. I am executing this query on a shell srv currently

Comment: oh i would suggest if you upgrade your mongodb version there are lots of new features in latest version, and if you don't want to then i have added second option with $project stage.

Comment: I will look into upgrading but for now, I will use the other option. Many thanks